# Copying files to other folder whose name is on the excel file

Tags: c, excel

In folder A, whose location is D:\Folder A , there are 8000 songs.
In Excel C.xlsx, whose location is D:\List , there are 1000 song titles.
or
In C.txt, there are same 1000 song titles. Each line has one song title.

I hope that I can copy files in folder A whose name is on the Excel C.xlsx or C.txt , to folder B, whose location is D:\Folder B.

How can i do so with c code?
*song titles are in column A, in excel sheet 1.
*song's format is .MP3 and .wav.

Comment: do you really need to do it in c? I think it's easier to write a batch or powershell script.

Comment: oh...well.. I thought so cause C is the only language i know :-( Anyway thanks! I'll try it!!